# Confusion regarding Overriding toString() method in a Class(Data class or POJO) and calling list.toString()?

Tags: java, list, class, tostring

I have this kind of implementation

```
static class InnerClassStudent{
        String name;
        int age;

        InnerClassStudent(String name,int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "name :" + name + "," + "age: " + age;
        }
    }
```

And then I create, add and print the item in List.

```
List<InnerClassStudent> listOfInnerClassStudent = new ArrayList<InnerClassStudent>();

//add items

//print items
 System.out.println("InnerClasslist : " + listOfInnerClassStudent.toString());
```

Then the output is

```
InnerClasslist : [name :Mr.B,age: 21, name :Mr.Y,age: 19, name :Mr.C,age: 30]
```

So, here I have some confusion regarding the toString() Method.
I am calling **list.toString()**, which means toString() needs to be a function of inside List class or its parent class.

So, its actual implementation is in **Object.java**

```
  public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
    }
```

So, my question and confusion is, when I **Override** the toString() in my required class, how does it all work together to print the List Of Items accordingly mentioned in the **Overridden** toString() method.

I hope I have made my question clear enough. Thank You.

Comment: The List overrides `toString()` too. And calls .`toString()` on each element, to build a bigger String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` has its own implementation of `toString` inherited from `AbstractCollection`

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
```

AbstractList definition,

```
public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>
```

,

```
public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh, yes , List is Abstraction, so the implementation is in ArrayList , and inside that it iterates and calls the overidden toString() method.  
But why cannot  I find toString() in ArrayList.java when view it in IntelIj or Android Studio.

Comment: Because it is inherited from `AbstractCollection`

Comment: Look at it's superclass. AbstractCollection or something similar.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the hierarchy. Hope it helps

Comment: ok, I got it, ArrayList extends AbstractList, and AbstractList extends AbstractCollection. And there is the definition of the toString() method which I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my confusion about how all this was connected and working together.